# Mirroring is failing in MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I m trying to set Mirroring in MS SQL Server 2016.

Everything looks fine still mirroring is failing with error:
Database 'DatabaseName' cannot be open. It is in the middle of a restore. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:927)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008208/sql-server-2016-cant-start-mirror)

Comment: Have you read this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c233823e-93c8-40bc-b699-e43999292c5a/sql-server-error927-and-restoring?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Yes, but no resolution was provided there either :-(